# Deprecated error after upgrade PHP Version

Tags: php, deprecated, php-8.1

I was using below formula in PHP. It was working fine till PHP 7.4. Now I have upgraded to PHP 8.1 and it's giving error.

```
<?php
    echo ((float)13.5 + intdiv((float)13.5, (int)10) * (float)2.5 / (int)12);
```

I'm getting error **Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Implicit conversion from float 13.5 to int loses precision**

How can I solve this? What is the reason for this error?

Comment: try `intdiv((int)(float)13.5, 10)`

Comment: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string contains more details

Comment: Also, why do you want to use `intdiv` on float numbers? Maybe it was "working", but did it also return the result you expected?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `intdiv` with a `float` argument doesn't make much sense, and may or may not have actually been giving the result you wanted

Taking out the superfluous casts, we have

```
(13.5 + intdiv(13.5, 10) * 2.5 / 12)
```

The `13.5` is **truncated** to an integer, so that becomes:

```
(13.5 + intdiv(13, 10) * 2.5 / 12)
```

It's possible you instead expected it to **round** the value, giving:

```
(13.5 + intdiv(14, 10) * 2.5 / 12)
```

For the example of 13.5, the answer is the same, but assuming that's actually a variable, it would give different examples for 19.5, for instance:

```
echo (13.5 + intdiv(19, 10) * 2.5 / 12); # 13.708333333333
echo (13.5 + intdiv(20, 10) * 2.5 / 12); # 13.916666666667
```

To make it explicit, you could use the [floor](https://php.net/floor) or [round](https://php.net/round) functions on the float first, *then* cast it to an int (since the result of rounding is still technically a float):

```
echo (13.5 + intdiv((int)floor(19.5), 10) * 2.5 / 12); # 13.708333333333
echo (13.5 + intdiv((int)round(19.5), 10) * 2.5 / 12); # 13.916666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `intdiv()` function requires two arguments with type `int`: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.intdiv.php

But you're passing `float` variable as the 1st argument, which causes implicit type conversion.

You should somehow convert your float variable into `int` before passing into the function.
This way:

```
intdiv((int)13.5, 10)
```

or this way:

```
intdiv(round(13.5), 10)
```

the rest of types you specified make no sense because PHP will figure it out automatically the same way.

Comment: It's worth noting that `round()` returns a float not an int, so there's still an implicit conversion going on, just one that PHP knows is safe.

Comment: @IMSoP Can you post the valid and safe answer?

Comment: @m2dev What's "valid" depends what you're actually trying to achieve; as noted in comments, passing a float to `intdiv` doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place. The first example in this case is _equivalent to your old code_, which truncates the 13.5 to 13; whether that's what you _intended_, only you can answer.

Comment: nice note @IMSoP you're absoultely right. Technically it's still `float`, but now it has no fraction, so PHP can safely convert it to `int`.

Comment: @Stalinko Yeah, the only reason it matters is that if you are in `strict_types=1` mode, you will still get an error after using `round`: https://3v4l.org/2A1el so would need to make the cast to int explicit: https://3v4l.org/K05WO